# CouchDb : Deleting a huge document first time gives Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)

Tags: couchdb, couchdb-futon, couchdb-python

When I try to delete a document (5Mb) in couchdb for the first time , I get this 
Status: 500 (Internal Server Error)  {"error":"os_process_error","reason":"{exit_status,1}"}

While deleting the document the 2nd time deletes it correctly.
This problem doesn't occur on windows but occurs on unix instance of couchdb.

Can anyone advise on this strange behavior ?

Comment: You should check if there's is any useful information in the logs for the CouchDB server.

Comment: resolved as https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1792